# Write stream got from Invoke-RestMethod to image file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, stream

I have a Asp.Net Web API which can return image stream to client.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(string imageId)
{
    ...
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    return response;
}
```

With fiddler, I can see the image was downloaded successfully. What I want to achieve is save it to local image with PowerShell.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod ...
```

I got the `$result`, but don't know how to save it to local disk, I've tried these ways:

```
# 1
$result | Out-File ".../test.png"

# 2: this exception said the $result is a string, cannot convert to Stream
$fs = New-Object IO.FileStream "...\test.png","OpenOrCreate","Write"
([System.IO.Stream]($result)).CopyTo($fs)
```

What the right way to save the image to local with PowerShell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-OutFile` switch:

```powershell
$url = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b"
Invoke-RestMethod $url -OutFile somefile.png
```

You could also use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Comment: But the `$result` is not a url, it's stream.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` must have a target url, you _are_ aiming a GET request at something(?)

Comment: Hmm, you are correct. Thanks very much, it worked. Actually I tried `$result | Out-File ..` before, that doesn't work.